# Symfony SSL connect error for in http client

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-client

I use http client component in my project symfony for external apis but I found this error when i test api:

> SSL connect error for url

configuration of component is basic configuration and also create for request if simple with request method

```
   $client = $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        $this->getUrl($route) . $query,
        $this->options
    );
```

I use a certificate for https and I enabled openssl extension, also I try to user verify_peer option in options parameters but also error.

How to fix this error?